# Consulta con parámetro y utilizando like

Tags: sql

Tengo esta consulta en un proceso almacenado, pero envía error en la condición Where específicamente en el operador like; espero me puedan ayudar.

```sql
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

Declare @Anio nvarchar(max)

Set @Anio = '2023'

Set @sql =  'UPDATE A '

Set @sql = @sql + 'SET A.[Tip_Recur] = ' +  'AD' + ' '

Set @sql = @sql + 'FROM [EJERCICIO].[dbo].[Tab_Resultado] As A '

Set @sql = @sql + 'Where  A.[Etiqueta_Id] = ' + 'Oficial' + ' and  (A.[Anio_Doc_FI]  < ' + @Anio + ' or A.[Anio_Doc_FI] like ' +  'D%' + ') and (A.[Anio_Doc_FI] <> ' + ' ' + ' and A.[Anio_Doc_FI] <> ' + '' + ' and (A.[Anio_Doc_FI]) is not null) '

 exec(@sql)
```

Saludos y en espera de sus comentarios.

Comment: Esto tiene muchos problemas. ¿Por qué estás usando código dinámico? No hay nada en esto que indique que se requiera. ¿Por qué tienes letras en una columna de año? ¿Esto es parte de algo más grande? Deberías dar una mejor perspectiva si es así porque la mejor solución para esto es eliminar por completo el código dinámico.

Comment: Es una base de datos financiera, efectivamente en esa columna Año tiene letras, ya que le ponen etiquetas para identificar ciertos registros ya sea por año o año y una letra especifica; así la diseñaron; solo que ahora necesitan sacar información en base al criterio mencionado.

Answer (score 0):

El operador like espera encontrar una cadena entre comillas simples, que deben quedar dentro de la cadena que contiene el SQL, por ejemplo:

```sql
Set @sql = @sql + 'Where  A.[Anio_Doc_FI] like ''' +  'D%' + ''';'
```

En SQL la manera de introducir una comilla en una cadena es usar una doble comilla. Por ejemplo `'Los 90''s'` contiene la cadena *Los 90's* y `' like ''D%'''` contiene la cadena  `like 'D%'`

Puedes asegurarte de haber producido una sentencia válida haciendo `print` de la variable `@sql` antes de ejecutarla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, deja me pongo a probar